# Loading Documents With Scripts in Ajax Tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to call some script in a newly ajax loaded tab but it looks like the script blocks inside the tab are not being processed at all so when I go to call a function in the tab the function cannot be found.  Is there a way to properly load the tab content such that the scripts are interpreted?

I have tried playing with the ajax options but that doesn't seem to help.

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
            ajaxOptions: {
                error: function (xhr, status, index, anchor) {
                    $(anchor.hash).html("This tab not yet built, sorry bub.");
                },
                dataType: 'html'

            },
            spinner: 'Loading tabs...',
        });
```

In the tabs I have something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function SetupTab(){
     alert('loaded');
   }
</script>
```

but

```
$("#tabs").bind("tabsshow", function(event, ui){ SetupTab();});
```

cannot find SetupTab.  Even if I allow the tab to load and then attempt to call SetupTab from firebug it can't be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you try and bind any events/actions to a html element that does not exist yet i.e.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 //apply elemnt bindings here
});
```

when you do load the elements using ajax the elements will not take on the bindings you supplied on document ready because they did not exist at that point.

Add a call back to your ajax call to then bind any events/functions to ur new html elements, then this should work.

I think thats what you was reffering to.

**EDIT:** try this.

```
$("#tabs").bind("tabsshow", function(event, ui){ alert('loaded');});
```

**EDIT AGAIN:** you could try this.

make sure the page you are loading just contains the script itself and not the script tags and then use:

```
//lets say the data returned from your ajax call:
data = function SetupTab(){alert('loaded');}
eval(data);
```

then you could call that function no problem.

**EDIT 3RD TIME:** if you cant remove the script tags from the page your load you could regex the html. with this pattern.

```
pattern = /<script\b[^>]*>(.*?)</script>/i
urscript = data.match(pattern);
eval(urscript[1]);
```

this should work.

Comment: It isn't elements I'm having trouble with but scripts which reside inside the newly loaded tab.

Comment: Exactly, it's because they reside within the HTML, and that you tell your Ajax script the returned value is HTML when there's a cript embedded.

Comment: As per the $.ajax documentation 
dataType
"html": Returns HTML as plain text; included script tags are evaluated when inserted in the DOM.

What data type should I be using?

Comment: wouldnt this be easier? $("#tabs").bind("tabsshow", function(event, ui){ alert('loaded');});

Comment: It would be, but that moves the logic from the tab to the page containing the tab.  I don't want that since it breaks the encapsulation of the tab content and behaviour.  My loading page would have to be aware of what tabs were loading and what each one of them looked like.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is also to detach your ajax call from the element (do just $.getScript for example).
Your loading tabs function should do something like this:

```
<div class="tabs" onclick="$.getScript('myScript.php?index='+$(this).index(#tabs"))">...
```

Then the server-side script should return something like this:

```
echo '
$("#tabs").eq('.$_GET['index'].')html("'.$myHTML.'");
/* Then the rest of your JS script (what you had in your HTML output) */
';
```